# extracting hashtags from tweets

Tags: r, statistics, analytics, hashtag, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to perform sentiment analysis and facing a small problem. I am using a dictionary which has hashtags and some other junk value(shown below). It also has associated weight of the hashtag. I want to extract only the hashtags and its corresponding weight into a new data frame. Is there any easy way to do it?
I have tried using regmatches, but some how its giving output in list format and is messing things up.
Input:

```
            V1    V2
1    #fabulous 7.526
2   #excellent 7.247
3      superb 7.199
4  #perfection 7.099
5    #terrific 6.922
6 #magnificent 6.672
```

Output:

```
            V1    V2
1    #fabulous 7.526
2   #excellent 7.247
3  #perfection 7.099
4    #terrific 6.922
5 #magnificent 6.672
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work and will give you desired output as data.frame

```
 Input<- data.frame(V1 = c("#fabulous","#excellent","superb","#perfection","#terrific","#magnificent"), V2 = c("7.526",  "7.247" , "7.199", "7.099",  "6.922", "6.672")) 
 extractHashtags <- Input[which(substr(Input$V1,1,1) == "#"),]
 View(extractHashtags)
```

Answer (score 5):

To select only the entries that are hashtags you can use the simple regex `^#` (meaning "anything that starts with a #"):

```
> input[grepl("^#",input[,1]),]
            V1    V2
1    #fabulous 7.526
2   #excellent 7.247
4  #perfection 7.099
5    #terrific 6.922
6 #magnificent 6.672
```

Otherwise from your original data, the regex `#[[:alnum:]]+` (meaning: "an hashtag, followed by 1 or more alphanumerical characters") should help you grab the hashtags:

```
> tweets <- c("New R job: Statistical and Methodological Consultant at the Center for Open Science http://www.r-users.com/jobs/statistical-methodological-consultant-center-open-science/ … #rstats #jobs","New R job: Research Engineer/Applied Researcher at eBay http://www.r-users.com/jobs/research-engineerapplied-researcher-ebay/ … #rstats #jobs")
> match <- regmatches(tweets,gregexpr("#[[:alnum:]]+",tweets))
> match
[[1]]
[1] "#rstats" "#jobs"  

[[2]]
[1] "#rstats" "#jobs"  
> unlist(match)
[1] "#rstats" "#jobs"   "#rstats" "#jobs"
```